# A basic vanilla javascript AJAX loader

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to write a simple function to return data from an ajax call. Here is what I have

```
var mytext = "";

function load(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onloadend = function(e){
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
}

var mytext = load('window.html');

console.log(mytext);
```

I am stuck, How do I get the returned value? I'ts a function in a function and I am lost :(

Comment: use a callback argument, dispatch an event (like native XMLHttpRequest does - though, why would you duplicate this way of doing AJAX), or return a Promise (like native fetch does) - whichever way you decide you'll never be able to use the function like `var result=load(url)` - since you need to deal with asynchrony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are serveral ways to do that. Since you seems to be new to javascript, you can start with `callback`:

```js
function load(url, callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onloadend = function(e){
        callback(xhr);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}

load('/', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

In this example, `callback` is a function, and we pass `xhr` as a parameter to that function while calling.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading up on callbacks and just needed a simple example to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to make use of the `Promise` and `fetch` APIs.

```
function ajax(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(options.url, {
      method: options.method,
      headers: options.headers,
      body: options.body
    }).then(function (response) {
      response.json().then(function (json) {
        resolve(json);
      }).catch(err => reject(err));
    }).catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
  const ajaxResponse = await ajax({url: '/some/api/call', method: 'get'});
```

In case you don't already know, `await` can only be used inside `async` functions. If you don't want to use `async` functions, do the following:

```
ajax({url: '/some/api/call', method: 'get'}).then(data => {
  // process data here
});
```

### Explanation:

JavaScript is a single-threaded language. This means everything runs in a blocking manner. If your Ajax call takes 3 seconds, then JavaScript will pause for 3 seconds. Luckily, the `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` APIs combat this issue by using asynchronous functions, meaning code can continue running while the Ajax call is awaiting a response.

In your code, you're not getting a response from your function because the Ajax call doesn't stop the execution, meaning by the time the call has been made, there's nothing to return yet and by the time the call is finished, the function's call is long in the past too. You can tell JavaScript however to keep track of this asynchronous task through `Promise`s. When your task is finished, the `Promise`'s `then` function is called with the data from the Ajax call.

JavaScript also provides syntactic sugar to make reading asynchronous code easier. When we use an `async` function, what we're actually doing is creating a regular function, whose body is wrapped in a `Promise`.

This also means that when you want to wait for the result of a previous `Promise`, you can prepend `await` in front of the `Promise` reference and await the completion of the `Promise`.

So you may have code that looks like this:

```
const call = await ajax({ ... });
console.log(call);
```

which actually translates to the following:

```
ajax({ ... }).then(call => {
  console.log(call);
});
```